# ExtJs NumberField Validation

Tags: validation, extjs

I have a composite element like below

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield'
    ,hideLabel: true
    ,labelWidth: 100
    ,items: [
        {
            xtype: 'displayfield'
            ,width: 160
            ,value: 'field 1'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'field1name',
            id: 'field1id',
            checked: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'displayfield'
            ,width: 20
            ,value: 'Ft '
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            width: 50,
            allowNegative: false,
            value: 50,
            name: 'numberfield'     
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I have a custom validation for the `xtype:'numberField'`?

I do not want to put the config option `allowBlank:false`, but instead, I want to validate it somewhere else, but display an error message on the side of the field.

Can anyone please explain to me how to do it?

Below is how I am doing it, which produces "invalid method" error in firebug:

```
Ext.get('numberfield').setActiveError('this Field Cannot be Blank');
```

and

```
Ext.get('numberfield').markInvalid('this Field Cannot be Blank');
```

Comment: If you only want to validate if it has values inside, you should use `allowBlank: false`. If you want a custom message, you only need to specify  `blankText: 'custom text'`.
For truly custom validation, there is the [validator](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-validator) config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think easiest is to use a validator function:

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield'
    ,hideLabel: true
    ,labelWidth: 100
    ,monitorValid: true
    ,items: [
        [...]
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            width: 50,
            allowNegative: false,
            value: 50,
            name: 'numberfield',
            validator: function(val) {
                if (!Ext.isEmpty(val)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return "Value cannot be empty";
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to run that validator? Thanks. I want to validate this field based on selection of some other fields in the form. so this validator runs as soon as i submit the form.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call it, it will be called automatically if you use `monitorValid: true` in the FormPanel configuration.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you the place where you need to add that.

Comment: ok As you can see in my code i have a check box, if the check box is selected then the numberfield should not be blank, else it can be blank. I am basically looking to validate the numberfield based on checkbox. thank you...

Comment: Oh, I see. Try then with your approach, but set an `id: 'my-number-field'` and use that in `Ext.get`.

Comment: When I try that with name or Id, firebug has error saying Ext.get("my-number-field").setActiveError is not a function. how to get the handle for the numberfield so that i can use its public methods?

Comment: Hmm, try using firebug's console to figure out if Ext.get("my-number-field") is returning undefined or some other component. Maybe you call it before the form is actually created?

Answer (score 2):

In Extjs4, you can set the property `allowBlank` to `false` to prevent empty numeric field entries.

There's also a `minLength` setting to limit the number of characters that must be entered.