# Extjs Form Validation before Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, extjs, extjs4

I have an Extjs form which it needs some validations like when I enter letters instead of numbers, it should alert me before I submit. direct before I enter one number in the field. How can I build that ?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699657/extjs-numberfield-validation)?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
onFormSubmit: function(btn, event) {
        var me        = this,
        form      = btn.up('form').getForm();
        if(form.isValid()) {
            //submit form
        }
        else alert('Invalid form');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
buttons: [{
    text: "Continue",
    margin: "0 5 10 0",
    handler: function () {
        var getForm = this.up("form").getForm();
        if (getForm.isValid()) {
            code her if form is valid
        } else {
             Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: "ERROR-A1001",
                msg: "Please fill the required fields correctly.",
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
            });
        }
    }
}]
```